# Is there a way to use .innerHTML multiple times?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to write two variable values into a div container (with id myDiv) using innerHTML. My Div container is only showing the second value.

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<input type="text" id="First" name="firstname">
<input type="text" id="Last" name="lastname">

<div id="myDiv"></div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("John").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("Mail").value;
    document.getElementById("myDub").innerHTML=x;
    document.getElementById("myDub").innerHTML=y;
}</script>
```

Comment: `+=` instead of `=`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First you need to use correct ids everywhere. Second you can just add `x+y` in one assignment only like this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
<input type="text" id="First" name="firstname">
<input type="text" id="Last" name="lastname">

<div id="myDiv"></div>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("First").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("Last").value;
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML= x + y;
}</script>
```

or you can use `+=` for if you want to keep appending to previously assigned value.

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = x;
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML += y;
```

Comment: This Worked Great!

Comment: Saviour, Literally! _/\\_